# Why do t-butyl and isopropyl groups deshield the ipso carbon in C13 NMR more than a Me group?

Tags: nmr-spectroscopy

I have a t-butyl group attached to an aromatic ring and I am confused about why it increases the shift of the ipso carbon about 20ppm. I know that C is slightly more electronegative than H, and this explains why Me increases the shift by about 8ppm, but why is the deshielding more for t butyl and isopropyl? Wouldn't extra hyperconjugation effects shield it rather than deshield?

Comment: Do you know what is hyper conjugation means? Methyl has only 3 hydrogens, but isopropyl has 6 and t-Bu has 9 (if I understand your question correctly). Put some more details to your question so9 that everybody'd understand it easily.

Comment: I understand the hyperconjugation but wouldn't that shield the nucleus which is the opposite of what i am seeing in my spectrum? Is it some kind of magnetic anisotropic effect which is deshielding the nucelus of the ipso carbon?